# When a certain value in one column, a new value in a new column

Tags: r

Depending on a value in one column I want a value in a new column. When visit 1, I want 7 in column "new", when visit 2 I want 8 in column "new" and when visit 3 I want 9 in the column "new".

```
id <- rep(1001:1003, each=3)
visit <- rep(1:3,3)
trt <- rep(c("A","B","C"),3)
df <- data.frame(id,visit,trt)

    id visit  trt
1 1001     1   A
2 1001     2   B
3 1001     3   C
4 1002     1   A
5 1002     2   B
6 1002     3   C
7 1003     1   A
8 1003     2   B
9 1003     3   C

I want it to look like:
    id  visit trt new
1 1001     1   A   7
2 1001     2   B   8
3 1001     3   C   9
4 1002     1   A   7
5 1002     2   B   8
6 1002     3   C   9
7 1003     1   A   7
8 1003     2   B   8
9 1003     3   C   9
```

I got his far but now I don't know how to continue. Does anyone have guidance to give? Thanks!

```
df %>%mutate(new=(visit==2))

    id visit trt   new
1 1001     1   A FALSE
2 1001     2   B  TRUE
3 1001     3   C FALSE
4 1002     1   A FALSE
5 1002     2   B  TRUE
6 1002     3   C FALSE
7 1003     1   A FALSE
8 1003     2   B  TRUE
9 1003     3   C FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for an answer which works in generic situations:

```
require(dplyr)

df = df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(new = case_when(.$visit == 1 ~ 7,
                                .$visit == 2 ~ 8,
                                .$visit == 3 ~ 9))
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need to add 6 to the row `visit`?

```
> df %>% mutate(new=visit+6)
    id visit trt new
1 1001     1   A   7
2 1001     2   B   8
3 1001     3   C   9
4 1002     1   A   7
5 1002     2   B   8
6 1002     3   C   9
7 1003     1   A   7
8 1003     2   B   8
9 1003     3   C   9
```

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers are 1, 2, 3  and are in order as shown , you can just add 6 to your `visit` column

```
df$new <- df$visit + 6
```

If you can't find any relation to update the values you can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(new  =case_when(visit == 1 ~ 7, 
                         visit == 2 ~ 8, 
                         visit == 3 ~9, 
                         TRUE ~NA_real_))
```